# stop dltk indexing on particluar folders - eclipse indigo (3.7) w/ pdt

Tags: eclipse-pdt, dltk

When i build/deploy my php project using an ant task within eclipse, it creates a copy of the files in a build folder then zips them, then deletes the folder

On big projects after copying the files, dltk tries to index the folder while im copying/zipping.

can i make dltk indexing ignore my build folder?

Comment: Where is the folder? Inside the project??

Comment: yep i have multiple projects and it creates a build/ folder inside each project when build/deploying the apps

Answer (score 11, accepted):

sure, you can exclude a specific folder by right clicking on the project, selecting PHP Build path, then go to the project entry > Excluded and select "Exclude". Add the pattern of your temporary folder.